# Click event is opening the wrong dialog in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, internet-explorer

I have a website that has several buttons that open different jQuery ui dialog boxes.

Inside one of those dialogs (with an id of `filter_story`) is a text field in which a user can type in keywords that I use later to filter stories when polling the server.  I have the text field set-up so that a user can enter several keywords, clicking a button of class `approve_filter_item` after entering each item, or the user can simply click the `enter` button between each keyword.

```
// button to open the keyword filter list
$( "#filter_stories" ).click(
     function(){
       $( "#filter_dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
     }
);

$(".approve_filter_item").click(function(){
  [process the just inserted keyword and then put focus back on the textfield]
});

//listen for enter key when user's focus is on entering a new keyword
$(".new_filter_item").keydown(function (e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    $($(this).parents("tr")[0]).find(".approve_filter_item").click();
  }
});

// button to show the post story dialog form
$( "#post_a_story" ).click( 
    function(){
      $( "#new_story_form" ).dialog( "open" );
    }
);
```

Everything works exactly as expected in all versions of Chrome, FF and Safari.  I'm experiencing some bad behavior, however, in IE.

Say an IE user enters a keyword in the `#filter_stories` dialog, and then clicks `enter`; what happens is the `keydown` event listener triggers as expected, but after it executes the click event listener for `#post_a_story` also triggers.  Previously, I used `keyup` instead of `keydown`, and in that case the `#post_a_story` click-event mysteriously triggered immediately when a user clicked `enter`, and my `keyup` event listener never triggered at all. If I remove the `post_a_story` event listener altogether, another one of my dialog boxes opens up instead.  Why is an `enter` key press triggering unrelated `click` events?

Note that if the user clicks the `approve_filter_item` button instead of clicking `enter`, the keyword is processed just as expected.

Comment: Do you have any listeners for the submit event on the form element? Maybe that's what is being triggered. Are you preventing the default behavior when ENTER is pressed?

Comment: I didn't have any listeners anywhere up the dom, and the dialog only opened in ie.  Still, returning false from my click event listener did stop the event from bubbling up to some unseen listener in ie.  So, @bfavaretto, if you'd like to submit your comment as an answer I'd be happy to accept it.  Also, I'd love to know if other people have ever noticed this type of behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @bfavaretto pointed out, .preventDefault() put an end to this weird ie behavior. I have no idea why it happened in the first place.